# VS2012 Debug mode doesn't read the <project>.exe.config file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, code-access-security

In my app.config file I have the following segment:

```xml
<runtime>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true" />
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="bin" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This is required to use "Pos for .Net" in the .Net4 environment.

When i run my project in the debug environment, I get an exception thrown because the above code has not been 'actioned'.

If I run the compiled assembly in the debug directory where the .exe.config file resides, no exception is thrown and the program runs OK.

I've checked VS2012 Debug configuration that the program is set to startup in the debug directory.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: Either edit the project.vshost.exe.config file instead or disable the hosting process.  Project + Properties, Debug tab.

Comment: @Hans The code is already included in the <project>.vshost.exe.config file. Makes no difference.

Comment: You are not leaving anything else to guess at.  You didn't document the exception, you faked the file name, no way we can tell what else might be wrong.  Document your question better.

Comment: @Hans Disabling the Hosting process fixed the issue.

Comment: Closing due to the fact the OP answered his own question in the comments without posting a answer.